# Filling a select with a series of times in increments, plus additional options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Using Ruby on Rails, I'm filling a 'select' with times using a given increment, such as every 30 minutes.
Currently I'm writing out all the possibilities in a YAML file, but i feel like there's a slicker way. I'm thinking I want to provide a start_time, an end_time, an increment, and currently just one more option called 'Closed' (think 'business_hours').
So, my select might display:

> 'Closed'
>
> 5:00am
>
> 5:30am
>
> 6:00am
>
> ...
>
> [all the way to]...
>
> 11:30pm

Can anyone think of a better way of doing this, or is just 'spelling' them all out the best way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This answer is based on @emh answer.

```
def create_hours(parameters)
  start_time = parameters[:start_time] ? parameters[:start_time] : 0
  end_time = parameters[:end_time] ? parameters[:end_time] : 24.hours
  increment = parameters[:increment] ? parameters[:increment] : 30.minutes
  Array.new(1 + (end_time - start_time)/increment) do |i|
    (Time.now.midnight + (i*increment) + start_time).strftime("%I:%M %p")
  end
end
```

You can use it this way:

```
create_hours(:start_time => 5.hours, :end_time => 23.hours)
=> ["05:30 AM", "06:00 AM", "06:30 AM", "07:00 AM", "07:30 AM", "08:00 AM", 
    "08:30 AM", "09:00 AM", "09:30 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", 
    "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "01:00 PM", "01:30 PM", "02:00 PM", 
    "02:30 PM", "03:00 PM", "03:30 PM", "04:00 PM", "04:30 PM", "05:00 PM", 
    "05:30 PM", "06:00 PM", "06:30 PM", "07:00 PM", "07:30 PM", "08:00 PM", 
    "08:30 PM", "09:00 PM", "09:30 PM", "10:00 PM", "10:30 PM", "11:00 PM"]
```

To add "Closed" use:

```
["closed"] + create_hours(:start_time => 5.hours, :end_time => 23.hours)
```

You can also pass `:increment => 15.minutes` - by default it is set to `30.minutes`.

Answer (score 8):

```
["closed"] + Array.new(24.hours / 30.minutes) do |i|
  (Time.now.midnight + (i*30.minutes)).strftime("%I:%M %p")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `<select>` you might consider using the HTML5 `time` input type:

```
<input type='time' min='05:30' max='23:30' step='00:30' />
```

Since the `time` input is only available in HTML5 (indeed, only Opera supports it so far), you'll want a way for other browsers to use it. I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246136/how-do-i-build-a-gracefully-degrading-html5-range) about doing the same thing for a `<input type='range'>` element.